# how to check that my wcf servcice is running or not?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

i had developed a wcf service (using vs 2010) that interact with another application (written by myself in C# windowsForm).
So in my application i want to check if the service is running , then process the requests else first run the wcf service.

so how to check if the service is running in my application?

note that both (wcf and winform application) are in different solutions.

Comment: Go to IIS and browse your service.

Comment: how to do that in my winform application?

Answer (score 0):

Expose a service method named Test(whatever you like) and return `client.IsAlive()`;